# Difference in Matlab and Octave computation

Tags: matlab, octave

I have implemented a Naive Bayes classifier.  On Matlab, my classify function takes 2 minutes to run while octave takes 25 minutes to run the same code.  Does anyone know what causes ocatve to run slower so that I can tweak my code accordingly?

PS: I have to submit to a server which runs octave and not Matlab.

Comment: You'd have to post your code. But one thing is that newer MATLAB versions have the JIT compiler which fixed a lot of the inefficiencies of the `for`-loops and Octave doesn't have this yet. So if you have some loops, your octave code might benefit from vectorization.

Comment: Yes, my experience also is that the recent JIT compiler in MATLAB removes much of the historical benefit of vectorizing your code. If its very loop heavy, it will still suffer from loop slowdown in octave.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab does a lot of "hidden" optimization when running your code (Octave probably, too, but different ones). Many of these optimizations e.g. concern that parameters to functions are not copied if you do not modify these parameters in the function, but instead passed by reference. This can significantly speed up calculations when you e.g. pass around large matrices, since otherwise most of your computational time is spend on copying. There are many, many similar optimizations, and not all of them are documented at all.

Without specific knowledge of what you are computing, it's hard to guess where the difference comes from. I am not aware if octave has an equivalence to the matlab profiler, but if, I would use this to find out where octave spends all the time. For debugging, I would also recommend to download Octave to your PC and debug there.

Comment: Yes, there is a profiler since Octave 3.6 (released in January 2012) implemented by Daniel Kraft. Here's a [slide presentation showing the profiler](http://wiki.octave.org/wiki/images/c/cd/OctConf-2015-Slides-Profiling.pdf) at OctConf 2015 and of course, the [manual section for debugging](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Debugging.html).